# How to display week number in devExtreme date-box for angular?

Tags: angular, devextreme, week-number, datebox

I'm making an angular component that shows a calendar.
The date format should be "Week 29, 2019-07-19".
Also, I want to know how to customize the display Text - maybe using the template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DateBox have the [displayFormat](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxDateBox/Configuration/#displayFormat) option which allows you to change the formatting of the displayed value.

You can use the Globalize library that support "week of the year" formatting. The template will look like this: `<dx-date-box displayFormat="'week' ww, dd/MM/YYYY"></dx-date-box>`

You can also use custom format by defining the functions ["formatter"](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/Common/Object_Structures/format/#formatter) and ["parser"](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/Common/Object_Structures/format/#parser)

Comment: `displayFormat="'week' ww, dd/MM/yyyy` works!
Thank you.